# Error when I put the Form elements from React Native Elements

Tags: react-native

I'm making a LoginScreen but when I try to put the Form elements, that launch me an error.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, StatusBar, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements'
import normalize from '../components/Utils';

class LoginScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#14246C" barStyle="light-content" style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }} />
                <Image source={require('../img/background-login.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}/>

                <View style={styles.loginForm}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginTitle}>Inicio de sesión</Text>

                    <FormLabel>Usuario</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput onChangeText="Tu nombre de usuario"/>
                    <FormValidationMessage>Error message</FormValidationMessage>
                </View>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Invariant violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string  (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: It is your full code of `LoginScreen` component?

Comment: kindly post full code for better help.

Comment: What version of react native elements are you using? Can't find anything about these components in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not with the **"react-native-elements"** but you need to export the component either for named or default.

```
export default class <className> extends Component{
 render(){
   return(
     <your component>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: I have the export default in the final of the file. When I delete the <FormLabel> <FormInput> and <FormValidationMessage> show the screen without errors. Only when I put that elements, launch me an error